# Kinetic release date

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

is there a fixed release date for kinetic ?
I just found may but I didn't find any information about the current status

thanks for the information

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234298/kinetic-release-date/) by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 222 on 2016-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [ROS Kinetic Kame Beta has begun](http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2016-April/069982.html) posted to `ros-users` by Jackie, May 23rd is the current target:

> May 23rd, World Turtle Day, is still our official release date for ROS Kinetic and we are on track to meeting it! So mark it down into your calendar, and if you're a maintainer, plan to finish your releases before then to leave some breathing room.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2